# Built-in Screen goes blank when lowering resolution

Tags: xorg, hp, amd-graphics, amdgpu, 23.10

I have a three monitor setup like this.

[image: three monitor default setup]

Everything works fine like this. But whenever I set the Built-in Screen to a lower resolution, the Built-in Screen just goes blank. The other two screens keep working fine. When I set it back to 1920x1080 it comes back up. The screen space seems to be rendered, since I can move my mouse into it, and put windows in it. I can also take a screenshot of it.

[image: lower-resolution screenshot]

But nothing shows up on the laptop screen. The backlight is on and can still be adjusted. System Settings just acts like everything is fine.

[image: System Settings screenshot]

I did some searching and also tried ChatGPT, but the problem is so specific that I don’t really know what to look for.

I’m on **Kubuntu 23.10**. The laptop is an **HP Elitebook 845 G8**, with an **AMD Ryzen 7 PRO 5850U with Radeon Graphics**.

`sudo lspci -k -vvv -P -PP` gives me:

```
00:08.1/04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev d1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        DeviceName: Onboard IGD
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Cezanne [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series]
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort+ <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 74
        IOMMU group: 12
        Region 0: Memory at 460000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Region 2: Memory at 470000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
        Region 4: I/O ports at 1000 [size=256]
        Region 5: Memory at fb300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
        Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1+,D2+,D3hot+,D3cold+)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [64] Express (v2) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
                DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s <4us, L1 unlimited
                        ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset-
                DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
                        RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+
                        MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
                DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
                LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 8GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <64ns, L1 <1us
                        ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
                LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes, Disabled- CommClk+
                        ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
                LnkSta: Speed 8GT/s, Width x16
                        TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
                DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+ NROPrPrP- LTR-
                         10BitTagComp+ 10BitTagReq- OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt+ EETLPPrefix+, MaxEETLPPrefixes 1
                         EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
                         FRS-
                         AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
                DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis- LTR- 10BitTagReq- OBFF Disabled,
                         AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
                LnkCap2: Supported Link Speeds: 2.5-16GT/s, Crosslink- Retimer+ 2Retimers+ DRS-
                LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 8GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
                         Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
                         Compliance Preset/De-emphasis: -6dB de-emphasis, 0dB preshoot
                LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -3.5dB, EqualizationComplete+ EqualizationPhase1+
                         EqualizationPhase2+ EqualizationPhase3+ LinkEqualizationRequest-
                         Retimer- 2Retimers- CrosslinkRes: unsupported
        Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/4 Maskable- 64bit+
                Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
        Capabilities: [c0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=4 Masked-
                Vector table: BAR=5 offset=00042000
                PBA: BAR=5 offset=00043000
        Capabilities: [100 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
        Capabilities: [270 v1] Secondary PCI Express
                LnkCtl3: LnkEquIntrruptEn- PerformEqu-
                LaneErrStat: 0
        Capabilities: [2a0 v1] Access Control Services
                ACSCap: SrcValid- TransBlk- ReqRedir- CmpltRedir- UpstreamFwd- EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
                ACSCtl: SrcValid- TransBlk- ReqRedir- CmpltRedir- UpstreamFwd- EgressCtrl- DirectTrans-
        Capabilities: [2b0 v1] Address Translation Service (ATS)
                ATSCap: Invalidate Queue Depth: 00
                ATSCtl: Enable+, Smallest Translation Unit: 00
        Capabilities: [2c0 v1] Page Request Interface (PRI)
                PRICtl: Enable- Reset-
                PRISta: RF- UPRGI- Stopped+
                Page Request Capacity: 00000100, Page Request Allocation: 00000000
        Capabilities: [2d0 v1] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
                PASIDCap: Exec+ Priv+, Max PASID Width: 10
                PASIDCtl: Enable- Exec- Priv-
        Capabilities: [400 v1] Data Link Feature <?>
        Capabilities: [410 v1] Physical Layer 16.0 GT/s <?>
        Capabilities: [440 v1] Lane Margining at the Receiver <?>
        Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
        Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

`sudo lshw` gives me:

```
*-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: Cezanne [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                logical name: /dev/fb0
                version: d1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
                configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 mode=1920x1080 resolution=1920,1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
                resources: iomemory:40-3f iomemory:40-3f irq:74 memory:460000000-46fffffff memory:470000000-4701fffff ioport:1000(size=256) memory:fb300000-fb37ffff
```

`xrandr` gives me:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4480 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 1280x720+3200+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  40.00  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1440x900      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00* 
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   640x480       60.00  
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-2 connected 1920x1080+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1400x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DisplayPort-3 connected 1280x1024+0+56 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+  75.02  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

When setting the resolution from 1920x1080 to 1280x720 the Xorg log is:

```
[216181.451] (WW) AMDGPU(0): flip queue failed: Invalid argument
[216181.451] (WW) AMDGPU(0): Page flip failed: Invalid argument
[216181.484] (II) AMDGPU(0): Allocate new frame buffer 4480x1080
[216181.484] (II) AMDGPU(0):  => pitch 17920 bytes
[216181.598] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID vendor "FUS", prod id 1686
[216181.598] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[216181.598] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[216181.598] (II) AMDGPU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[216181.598] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz eP)
[216181.598] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[216181.598] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[216181.598] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[216181.598] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[216181.598] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[216181.598] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[216181.598] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[216181.598] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[216181.628] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID vendor "FUS", prod id 1686
[216181.628] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[216181.628] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[216181.628] (II) AMDGPU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[216181.628] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz eP)
[216181.628] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[216181.628] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[216181.628] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[216181.628] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[216181.628] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[216181.628] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[216181.628] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[216181.628] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[216181.664] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID vendor "FUS", prod id 1686
[216181.664] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[216181.664] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[216181.664] (II) AMDGPU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[216181.664] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz eP)
[216181.664] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[216181.664] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[216181.664] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[216181.664] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[216181.664] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[216181.665] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[216181.665] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[216181.665] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[216181.665] (WW) AMDGPU(0): flip queue failed: Invalid argument
[216181.665] (WW) AMDGPU(0): Page flip failed: Invalid argument
[216181.733] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID vendor "FUS", prod id 1686
[216181.733] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[216181.733] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[216181.733] (II) AMDGPU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[216181.733] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz eP)
[216181.733] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[216181.733] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[216181.733] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[216181.733] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[216181.733] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[216181.733] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[216181.733] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[216181.733] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[216181.759] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID vendor "FUS", prod id 1686
[216181.760] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[216181.760] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[216181.760] (II) AMDGPU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[216181.760] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz eP)
[216181.760] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[216181.760] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[216181.760] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[216181.760] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[216181.760] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[216181.760] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[216181.760] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[216181.760] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[216181.787] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID vendor "FUS", prod id 1686
[216181.787] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[216181.787] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[216181.787] (II) AMDGPU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[216181.787] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz eP)
[216181.787] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[216181.787] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[216181.787] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[216181.787] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[216181.787] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[216181.787] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[216181.787] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[216181.787] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[216181.816] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID vendor "FUS", prod id 1686
[216181.817] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[216181.817] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[216181.817] (II) AMDGPU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[216181.817] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz eP)
[216181.817] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[216181.817] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[216181.817] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[216181.817] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[216181.817] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[216181.817] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[216181.817] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[216181.817] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[216181.844] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID vendor "FUS", prod id 1686
[216181.844] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[216181.844] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[216181.844] (II) AMDGPU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[216181.844] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz eP)
[216181.844] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[216181.844] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[216181.844] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[216181.844] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[216181.844] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[216181.844] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[216181.844] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[216181.844] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[216181.869] (II) AMDGPU(0): EDID vendor "FUS", prod id 1686
[216181.869] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[216181.869] (II) AMDGPU(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[216181.869] (II) AMDGPU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[216181.869] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz eP)
[216181.869] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[216181.869] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[216181.869] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[216181.869] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[216181.869] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz e)
[216181.869] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[216181.869] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[216181.869] (II) AMDGPU(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
```

I didn't have any troubles in my previous ubuntu install, Kubuntu 22.04.

Could anybody give me some ideas. I don't know in which direction to look.

Comment: The same issue for me. (New on build-in screen on Kubuntu 23.10, Ryzen 7 PRO 6850U, ThinkPad X13...)

Comment: As a workaround, switching to previous kernel (6.2) makes the screen work https://askubuntu.com/a/1492618/29914

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update on February 8, 2024**

As can be seen on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2046504 a bugfix has been released for Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic). So the solution below is **no longer valid for Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic)**. As @FabianStreitel pointed out, the problem **still exists on Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy)**.

I haven't had time to figure how to switch back to the standard Ubuntu kernel yet.

---

I managed to get things working by installing a newer version of the kernel. (Thanks to the comment of @JanMolnár)

I used the [ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh](https://github.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh) script to download and install a different kernel version.

Since I have secure boot enabled, I had to be able to sign the different kernel version. I created and enrolled a kernel signing certificate using [ubuntu-sb-kernel-signing](https://github.com/berglh/ubuntu-sb-kernel-signing#creating-a-mok-for-kernel-signing).

I turned kernel signing on in ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh.

Since Ubuntu was on version 6.5.0, I started at v6.5.1, but all version from v6.5.1 up to v6.5.8 gave an error message

```
Downloading index from kernel.ubuntu.com
Abort, the amd64 build has not succeeded
```

So I ended up using v6.5.9.

The error for the amd64 build seems to be solved in the meantime for v6.5.1, v6.5.2 and v6.5.3, the others will probably also get solved.

I'm using v6.5.9 now and the screen is working perfectly again.

I hope someone will find use of my solution. If it's better to tackle this differently, please let me know :)

As @JanMolnár pointed out, a bug report is open at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2042867

Comment: In the meantime I have found https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2042867 which should fix it. Please tick "Does this bug affect you?" to increase its priority.

Comment: As of 6 Feb 24, on Ubuntu 22.04 I haven't received a working fix via the normal updates. The 6.5 kernel still has the same bug, reverting to 6.2 is the only real option at the moment AFAICS

Comment: @FabianStreitel based on a search https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux&searchon=sourcenames&exact=1&suite=all&section=all I would think that Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy) is still on 5.15.0-94.104. How did you get the 6.5 kernel?

Comment: Got an update today on 22.04 for kernel 6.5.0-17 which includes the fix

Comment: @NotizMe https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle#ubuntu-kernel-release-cycle indicates that 6.5 is indeed correct as 6.2 went out of support for 22.04 in January.